# General purpose database within BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

In my BizTalk server, I would like to create custom orchestrations for fetching data from various sources such as REST APIs, SFTP folders, etc. I would like to store the parameters of the REST API requests or SFTP access requests in a DB and use them in the Orchestration when making the request. I am aware BizTalk has a built-in SQL Server. Does it have a DB that can be used for storing such parameters or reference data or metadata?

Comment: There are several places that you can store data in BizTalk, 1)  Xref tables, useful for translation of items,  2) SSO for storting secrets & passwords.  Can you elaborate on what sorts of things you want to store?

Comment: A URL such as service.com/api/stockprice/<stockticker>/<fromdate>/<todate> needs to be invoked by BizTalk. I want to store the three params in a configuration that can be used for making the request.  There are several such API URLs that need to be called and they all have different params that need to be configured.

Comment: Are the fromdate & todate going to be changing regularly?  And are there going to be multiple stockticker numbers, are they going to be added to/removed on a regular basis?

Comment: from date and to date will change every week. There will be about 200 tickers for which the API has to be accessed one after another. The tickers will change once a month. 5-6 new tickers will get added or deleted.

Comment: Is the SQL Server used by BizTalk accessible to us to create our own DB?

Comment: It isn't recommended to create a custom DB in the same instance, but there is nothing stopping you having another instance on the same DB server that you could use.

Answer (score 0):

For this need, there are wo options

**Option 1:**

If you are dealing with only few values, you can add them to BTSNTSvc.exe.config and read your appSettings like a .Net config file

**Option 2 :**

Using SSO config. refer to [Biztalk config in SSO](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/559597/How-to-store-BizTalk-configuration-in-the-SSO-data)

Comment: Option 3. If they aren't secrets, in BRE rules

Comment: Sorry, but too complicated to manage some keys conf